# Very simple databinding crashes / GlobalOffsetZ / Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, xaml, windows-phone-7

HI there, I'm playing around with the new Windows Phone 7 SDK and have a prob here...

xaml

```
<Rectangle Fill="#FFFFEA00" Stroke="Black" Height="300" Width="300">
                <Rectangle.Projection>
                    <PlaneProjection GlobalOffsetZ="{Binding Path=Test}" />
                </Rectangle.Projection>
            </Rectangle>
```

c#

```
        private double test = 300;

    public double Test
    {

    get { return test; }

    set { test = value; }

    }

    public MainPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
```

result is a forced close on start and I don't understand why..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight 3 [doesn't allow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject%28VS.95%29.aspx)(See Version Notes) you to use bindings on non-FrameworkElements such as PlaneProjection see [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/197125/462193.aspx) for more details on your situation as well as one workaround.

Comment: mhh okay thank you.. but still wondering why blend then tells me I'm using Silverlight 4.. http://public.slay.it/MARTIN-PC/634195874063037790.png

Comment: I'm guessing that is just a quirk of blend, Silverlight for windows phone is based on V3 with some extensions. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426931%28VS.95%29.aspx where it says the new V4 features are not supported which includes 'Binding to DependencyObject instances.'